# Significance test on the difference of two correlation coefficient

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

How do you test if two correlation coefficients are signficantly different - in GNU R?

That is, if the effect between the same variables (e.g., age and income) is different in two different populations (subsamples).

For background information see [How do I compare correlation coefficients of the same variables across different groups](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13902/how-do-i-compare-correlation-coefficients-of-the-same-variables-across-different) and [Significance test on the difference of Spearman's correlation coefficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17696/significance-test-on-the-difference-of-spearmans-correlation-coefficient) (both at CrossValidated).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a ready-to-use function for GNU R if you want to compare multiple pairs of coefficients (based on [Significance of the difference between two correlation coefficients](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Significance-of-the-difference-between-two-correlation-coefficients-tt3063765.html#a3063946) and [Quantitative Analysis and Politics, PDF](http://imai.princeton.edu/teaching/files/Handout8.pdf)):

```
cor.diff.test = function(r1, r2, n1, n2, alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater")) {

  Z1 = 0.5 * log( (1+r1)/(1-r1) )
  Z2 = 0.5 * log( (1+r2)/(1-r2) )

  diff = Z1 - Z2
  SEdiff = sqrt( 1 / (n1 - 3) + 1 / (n2 - 3))
  diff.Z = diff / SEdiff

  if (alternative == "less") {
    return(pnorm(diff.Z, lower.tail=F))
  } else if (alternative == "greater") {
    return(pnorm(-diff.Z, lower.tail=F))
  } else if (alternative == "two.sided") {
    return(2 * pnorm( abs(diff.Z), lower.tail=F))
  } else {
    warning(paste("Invalid alterantive", alternative), domain=NA)
    return(NA)
  }
}
```

Comment: There is alraedy a `cor.test` function in the base `stats` package, so you may avoid using this name.

Comment: Please check out the revision 3 (http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14519007/3) of this posting for hyperlinks to online calculators and the original formula - just in case you only want to compare few pairs of correlation coefficients. For another user these hyperlinks looked like advertising and this user removed what I considered useful information.

Comment: Note: There is also a function `r.test()` in the `psych` package suitable for this task.

Answer (score 2):

The package [cocor](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cocor/) provides functions to test if two independent or dependent correlation coefficients are significantly different. There is also a web interface for the package available: http://comparingcorrelations.org